# Common ground between primary and secondary SMPS supply safe?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

Is it safe to use a secondary smps supply in another full-wave circuit (dc side after filtering) by  connecting smps ground to the corresponding ground of the primary?

What if the filtering of the primary is not proper , will the ripple/AC destroy the secondary supply?

[image]

Comment: so far that looks ok. but more details could change that.

Comment: You might want to draw the diodes in the bridge rectifier correctly, before we think about the details of what's going to work

Comment: @Neil_UK: Pic edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's OK provided that you realise that everything is now live, including the blue wire.

[image]

*Figure 1. Surprise awaits the unwary.*

Even if (1) is connected to neutral, high voltages will appear on (5).

Consider when (2) goes negative. Current will flow through diode (3) and point (4) will be at negative mains voltage + 0.7 V (for the diode drop). (5), the SMPS and DUT will be live.

When (2) goes positive diode (6) will be forward biased holding the blue line (5) at 0.7 V above (1).

Be very careful. Insulate everything. Do not connect oscilloscope probes to DUT (unless the 'scope is a fully insulated type such as the Fluke Scopemeter) as you risk shorting mains to ground through the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's going to blow up or get damaged, but you may introduce noise in some cases.

Switched-mode supplies are very noisey and you don't want that current flowing through ground in a sensitive or precision circuit.

You may be able to get away with it, especially with extra filtering of the primary supply, depending on what the primary supply is powering.

One example is an low noise audio circuit. You wouldn't want an SMPS anywhere near that. Sometimes the switching frequency is within the audio band and you can hear it.

That's just one example, but you can try it and see if it's acceptable for your design or not.